# Uncaught Syntax:Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know super basic question but I am at the beginning of my code journey!
I want to make that on Radio Button change that the image is changing too:
So I have added a event.listener and have saied if the the.value is even with any color do something.
Maybe thats all complete wrong but the acually problem i have right now with the console.log he gives me the falure:

Uncaught Syntax:Unexpected end of input

Maybe anyone sees a failure directly!
The link to my fun Project:

https://waldhoer.webflow.io/

Code:

```
<script>
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=Radio]').click(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    });
    
    if (this.value === red) {
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
       
        } else if (this.value === gold) {
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
        
        } else if (this.value === white) {
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
        };
    
</script>
```

Comment: put conditions inside `$('input[type=Radio]').click(function(){` just after `alert(this.value);`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` is not closed. I suppose that the closing tag after alert is misplaced and should go just before the end of the script. By the way I suppose that Red-Phone is not a variable then you need to quote it ( `getElementById("Red-Phone")`)

Comment: You are missing 1 } at the end

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed off the document ready function.

There is both a missing curly bracket which is the end of the function and a closing round bracket to match the opening bracket on the ready.

```
<script>
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=Radio]').click(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    });
    
    if (this.value === red) {
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
       
        } else if (this.value === gold) {
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
        
        } else if (this.value === white) {
            document.getElementById(Gold-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(Red-Phone).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(White-Phone).style.visibility = "visible";
        };
```

}); // HERE

```
</script>
```

If you use a text editor (like Notepad++ for example) it can probably highlight brackets for you so you can see where you have matches. I also find it useful to get it to count the number of opening and closing brackets of a particular type - if the counts aren't equal - go searching.

Comment: Thank you so much!You are my hero of the day:)